# Modal pop up fade in on open click and fade out on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, fade

I have a rather simple question for once. I have delete buttons that open modal pop ups to confirm or deny deletion. I would like these modal pop ups to fade in on click and fade out on cancel. I've tried a few different things already, no luck so far. I just need a simple solution. Thanks in advance. Here's my code

```
<style>
div.delModal
{   
    position:absolute;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:8px;
    background-color:white;
    width:160px;
    text-align:right
}
</style>
<script>
function showModal(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        //$(this).fadeIn('slow');
    }
    function hideModal(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type ="button" value="delete" onclick="showModal('delAll1')">

<div class="delModal" style="display:none" id="delAll1">
  <img src="images/warning.png" />&nbsp;Are you sure you want to delete vessel and the corresponding tanks?<br />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" onclick="hideModal('delAll1')"/>     
    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delVesselAll(1)" id="delete"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/CJXUX/

Comment: There is a scope issue in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8mhu7/ or http://jsfiddle.net/CHRNL/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` on your `id` parameter (`"delAll1"`) not on `this`.

```
function showModal(id) {
    $("#" + id).fadeIn('slow');
}
function hideModal(id) {
    $("#" + id).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

By using, `$("#" + id)` you can select an element by its `id`, that's `"#" + id`.

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bpDKL/)

**Note:** Change from `onLoad` to `no wrap (head)` under framework on the left sidebar to fix the scope issue.

Comment: #delModal? My id for that div is dellAll1, delSon and so on. Can you show a jsfiddle example? Otherwise the code looks perfect, just not working for me.

Comment: Beautiful, simple solution. Thanks so much @Alexander

Comment: @triplethreat77, perfect! I had a typo in my edit. Also, don't forget to mark the most helpful answer of your questions

Comment: I've got another issue that no matter how I word it, no one seems to have answers for. Maybe you do? @Alexander http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463030/add-values-to-correct-father-section-of-table

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't satisfied with your first two comments so I made a new fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dkmkX/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.deleteButton').each(function (i) {
    var whichModal = i; //use this index, a data attribute on the modal, or $(this).parent().parent() to find delete the actual item from the page
    var deleteModal = $(this).parent().find('.deleteModal');
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        deleteModal.fadeIn('slow');
    });
    $(this).parent().find('.modalDelete').click(function (e) {
        deleteModal.fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $(this).parent().find('.modalCancel').click(function (e) {
        deleteModal.fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
}); //ready
```

This will let you add multiple delete buttons each with their own modals.

There's a comment in the JS about how to find out which modal has been pressed, since this solution is ID independent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fadeIn()` on the right selector(`'#'+id`), `this` in the current context would be the global object.

```
function showModal(id) {   
    $('#'+id).fadeIn();
    //$(this).fadeIn('slow');
}
function hideModal(id) {
    $('#'+id).fadeOut();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/CJXUX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use id for each button like this

```
<input type ="button" value="show" id="show">

<div class="delModal" style="display:none" id="delAll1">
  <img src="images/warning.png" />&nbsp;Are you sure you want to delete vessel and the corresponding tanks?<br />
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="hide" id="delete"/>     
    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delVesselAll(1)" id="delete"/>
</div>
```

And the jquery like this

```
$("#show").click(function() {
        $("#delAll1").fadeIn();
    });
$("#delete").click(function() {
        $("#delAll1").fadeOut();
    });
```

Comment: Your answer although the closest to actual jquery, will not work if the user presses delete in the modal box. You would need to change **Cancel** input **id** to "cancel" and the second function would be this. `$("#cancel, #delete").click(function() {
        $("#delAll1").fadeOut();
    });`