# Add values to correct father section of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, parent-child, innerhtml

I have a dialog pop up with drop down selects, an input box and a save button. This save button updates the parent table with the user drop down/input values, but at at end of the table. I need these values to go under the chosen father part of the table. My drop down for the father has independent IDs, I'm just not sure how to implement it. I've tried to strip my code to work in jsfiddle, but the demo won't add values to the table. Here's my code for the dialog pop up:

```
<script>
$("#save").click(function () {          
    for(var j=0;j<document.getElementsByName("select1").length;j++) {
        updateParent1(document.getElementsByName("select1").item(j).value + '&nbsp;' +
                      document.getElementsByName("text1").item(j).value + '&nbsp; - ' +
                      document.getElementsByName("select2").item(j).value,
                      document.getElementsByName("chooseFather").item(j).value);                     
            }
        });
</script>

<form method="post" name="shoreInfo">
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <select name="select1" value="1">
          <option selected value="undefined">Select...</option>
          <option value="Value 1 (option1)">Value 1 (option1)</option>
          <option value="Value 1 (option2)">Value 1 (option2)</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <select name="chooseFather" value="4">
          <option selected value="undefined">Select...</option>
          <option id="father3">Choose to add this information under father3 row.</option>
          <option id="father4">Choose to add this information under father4 row.</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <select name="select2" value="3">
          <option selected value="undefined">Select...</option>
          <option value="Value 2 (option1)">Value 2 (option1)</option>
          <option value="Value 2 (option2)">Value 2 (option2)</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="text1" value="2" class="text94 apni"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Add values to table" id="save" />
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And here's the code for the parent page:

```
<script>
    function updateParent1(value1) {
            var table = document.getElementById("shore_tab");
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                //alert(rowCount);
                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    cell1.innerHTML = "";

                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    cell2.innerHTML = value1;

                    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
                    element1.type = "checkbox";
                    cell3.innerHTML = "<img title='remove'  src='images/delete-row-icon1.png' class='sub_icon remove'/> &nbsp;";
                    cell3.appendChild(element1);
    }
</script>

  <table id="shore_tab" border="1">
                      <tr class="row_blue_bold father" id="father3">
                        <td colspan="2" class="father_header">Category 3</td>
                        <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                            <tr class="row_blue_bold son3">
                              <td class="cell_20 cell_no_bkg">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="cell_190">(information for father3, category 3)</td>
                              <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="row_blue_bold son3">
                              <td class="cell_20 cell_no_bkg">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="cell_190">(information for father3, category 3)</td>
                              <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                      <tr class="row_blue_bold father" id="father4">
                        <td colspan="2" class="father_header">Category 4</td>
                        <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                            <tr class="row_blue_bold son4">
                              <td class="cell_20 cell_no_bkg">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="cell_190">(information for father4, category 4)</td>
                              <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="row_blue_bold son4">
                              <td class="cell_20 cell_no_bkg">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="cell_190">(information for father4, category 4)</td>
                              <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/8tfhn/

Comment: this works in jsFiddle if you add the JQuery library.