# insertRow() to specific row id

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic, innerhtml

Using

```
var row = table.insertRow(id);
```

how can I specify that the new row goes under the used chosen ID, rather than a hardcoded index or at the end of the table? I have a drop down that has different options of what row id to place your new row under. The drop down options have matching ids to the related rows. Thanks. Here is my table, I want the new row go go under the user selected father (father3, father4, or father5)

```
 <table id="shore_tab" border="1">
                      <tr class="row_blue_bold father" id="father3">
                        <td colspan="2" class="father_header">Category 3</td>
                        <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                            <tr class="row_blue_bold son3">
                              <td class="cell_20 cell_no_bkg">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="cell_190">(information for father3, category 3)</td>
                              <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="row_blue_bold son3">
                              <td class="cell_20 cell_no_bkg">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="cell_190">(information for father3, category 3)</td>
                              <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                      <tr class="row_blue_bold father" id="father4">
                        <td colspan="2" class="father_header">Category 4</td>
                        <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                            <tr class="row_blue_bold son4">
                              <td class="cell_20 cell_no_bkg">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="cell_190">(information for father4, category 4)</td>
                              <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="row_blue_bold son4">
                              <td class="cell_20 cell_no_bkg">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="cell_190">(information for father4, category 4)</td>
                              <td class="cell_50">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: You probably have to get the index of the row with that ID and pass it (+1) to `insertRow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the id to get the index

```
var row = table.insertRow(document.getElementById(id).rowIndex+1);//+1 to be inserted under
```

Comment: I updated my question. I need new rows to go under either father3, father4, or father5, depending on what the user chose from the drop down.

Comment: @triplethreat77 `id` will be the id the user chooses like `father3` etc

Comment: this seems like a perfect solution, but I can't get it to work. Can you take a look at my previous post? The code for the drop downs is there too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463030/add-values-to-correct-father-section-of-table

Comment: @triplethreat77 your `<option>`s had ids and not values, use these values to get the rowIndex of the required row see http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/8tfhn/1/

Comment: I thought I was going crazy. I copied the exact code to my document...and it wouldn't work. To realize my jsfiddle was in Chrome and my project is in IE. Musa, this works beautifully in Chrome, but unfortunately I must use it in IE.

Comment: @triplethreat77 The fiddle works for me in IE9, what version are you using?

Comment: IE8. Damn, and I have no other option.

Comment: @triplethreat77 just tried the fiddle in IE8 and it works, can you you make a fiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23165/discussion-between-triplethreat77-and-musa)

Comment: I got it, Musa. I had to remove the form surrounding the drop downs. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be `index`, that is: `table.rows` is like an Array (it's not actually an Array, but behaves like one).

Comment: var row = table.insertRow(0); Like this. But I don't want it at a specfied index of 0 or -3. I need it to place after a chosen row id.

Comment: Pass in the `index` of the row (not the `id` because there is no such thing).