# Adding animation to a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this popup here structured this way and I want to add a little animation to it. A fade would be simple and good solution.

The "button":

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('back_overlay').style.display='block';document.getElementById('portfolio_popup').style.display='block';">
                    <div class="port_item wow lightSpeedIn" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                        <h3>MATERIAIS DE CONSTRUÇÃO</h3>
                        <p>+</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

And the popup itself:

```
<div id="portfolio_popup">
    <div class="portfolio_antes">
        <h1>Antes</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio_depois">
        <h1>Depois</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hide_everything()"><div id="back_overlay" title="Fechar Popup"></div></a>
```

plus this little script here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function hide_everything() {
            $("#back_overlay").css('display', 'none');
            $("#portfolio_popup").css('display', 'none');
        }
    </script>
```

The thing is I don't have any idea how can I do such thing.

Will I have to change the way it is structured or can I have a solution for it?

Comment: Do you mean something similar to this?
http://www.gopiplus.com/work/2011/01/08/cool-fade-popup/#.VWdJLUa-6mt

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel I want it to appear when the `a` is clicked, not automatically.

Comment: You might try making a jsbin.com example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find it already answered on SO:
[Modal pop up fade in on open click and fade out on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447444/modal-pop-up-fade-in-on-open-click-and-fade-out-on-close)

Here is the jsfiddle:

```
<script>
function showModal(id) {
    $('#'+id).fadeIn('slow');
}
function hideModal(id) {
     $('#'+id).fadeOut('slow');
}    
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CHRNL/