# How to have the modal popup open and close in slow speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal popup with below implementation:

here is the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6m10g8kh/4/

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="modalDeliveryAddress" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close" onclick="closeModal('modalDeliveryAddress');">&times;</span>
                <h2>Your new delivery address</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="delivery-popup clearfix">
                    <div class="delivery-container">
                        <div style="padding-top:25px;"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="floor_no" class="form-control" id="floor-info" placeholder="Floor/Unit No.">

                        <input type="text" name="block_no" class="form-control" id="block-info" placeholder="Block No.">

                        <input type="text" name="street_name" class="form-control" id="street-info" placeholder="Street Name">

                        <input type="text" name="zip_code" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-format="ddddd" id="zip_info" maxlength="5" placeholder="Zip Code">
                        <div style="padding-top:25px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <a class="btn cancelBtn pull-left" href="#" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancel1" onclick="closeModal('modalDeliveryAddress');">Cancel</a>
                <a id="submitAdd" class="btn continue pull-right" href="#" name="submitAdd">Submit</a>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
function openModal(modal_Id) {
        var modalId = $('#' + modal_Id);
            modalId.show();
}

function closeModal(modal_Id) {
        var modalId = document.getElementById(modal_Id);
        modalId.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function (event) {

        switch (event.target.id) {
            case 'modalDeliveryAddress':
                document.getElementById(event.target.id).style.display = "none";
                break;
            case 'modalCCDetails':
                document.getElementById(event.target.id).style.display = "none";
                break;
            case 'modalDlvSchedule':
                document.getElementById(event.target.id).style.display = "none";
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

**CSS:**

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;

}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 92%;
    left:14px;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 0px 0px !important;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #000;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


a.cancelBtn{
    font-size: 20px !important;
    /* width: 300px;
    height: 45px; */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px #e7e9ea;
    color:#ed1a3d;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 40px;
}

a.continue, a.continue:visited {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    /* width: 300px;
    height: 45px; */
    background-color: #ed1a3d;
    border: solid 1px #e7e9ea;
    color:#ffffff;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 166px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 20px 14px 36px;
    background-color: #00b9e3;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 0px 0px !important;
    text-align: center;
    height:60px;
}

.modal-header h2{
    font-size: 20px !important;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 0px;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Now here, I have 2 problems:

1. Whenever the Modal box open up, it opens from bottom towards with a specific speed. What I need it is, to reduce the speed of opening this popup.
2. Also, whenever I close my popup, it doesn't animate the way it opens up, that is, it doesn't close moving from top towards bottom, rather it closes instantly. How to keep the seamless behavior of closing the popup with equal speed with which it opens up.

**What I have tried?**

I tried putting property `transitions: opacity 1.5s linear` in `.modal{}` css but it didn't seems to be working

**Note:** I have all required jquery library, bootstrap library included in header of page.

I have also tried fadeIn and fadeOut methods but it doesnt give me the desired behavior rather my modal box flickers when it opens up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modal pop up fade in on open click and fade out on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447444/modal-pop-up-fade-in-on-open-click-and-fade-out-on-close)

Comment: @DineshGhule I have already tried the fadeIn fadeOut methods, but it didnt worked. To understand the behavior in question please refer to the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6m10g8kh/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With respect to  tagged duplicate question, I have figured out the solution by extending the solution of using `fadeIn/fadeOut('slow')`. Below is the specifics required to implement it:

**CSS:**

```
.modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* Black w/ opacity */
        -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1.2s;
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #fefefe;
        width: 92%;
        left:14px;
        -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        border-radius: 16px 16px 0px 0px !important;
    }
```

In above css, I have tweaked `-webkit-animation-duration: 1.2s;` on `.modal` class and `-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;` in `.modal-content` class

To display and hide the modal box I have used below JS snippet:

**JS**

```
<script>
    function openModal(modal_Id) {
            var modalId = $('#' + modal_Id);
                modalId.fadeIn('slow');
     /* modalId.show() */;
    }

    function closeModal(modal_Id) {
    var modalId = $('#' + modal_Id);
                modalId.fadeOut('slow');
                /* modalId.hide() */;
    }

    window.onclick = function (event) {

            switch (event.target.id) {
                case 'modalDeliveryAddress':
                   $('#' + event.target.id).fadeOut('slow'); 
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The complete working implementation is available here:
https://jsfiddle.net/2cwwe0p4/1/